# Spring Boot Querydsl: Sorting - sometimes not working for specifc enitity attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

I am building a data warehouse with Spring Boot and Angular. For some tables I need a combination of searching, filtering, (multi-) sorting and pageing. Therefore I use Querydsl, it fits perfectly my needs. But I have some problems with it. After building the Java Application the sorting is sometimes not working for some attributes of my entity. Debugging showed that the `sorting` parameter within the `pageable` is `UNSORTED` for these specify attributes.

To make this more clear, I will show some code.
The Entity:

```java
Entity
@Table(name = "ExternalEffortLinkManagement", schema = "dbo")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "externalEffortLinkManagementId")
public class ExternalEffortLinkManagement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ExternalEffortLinkManagement_ID")
    private long externalEffortLinkManagementId;

    @Column(name = "Mitarbeiter")
    private String employee;

    @Column(name = "Jahr")
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "Monat")
    private int month;

    @Column(name = "Projektnummer")
    private String projectNumber;

    @Column(name = "InitialMailSent")
    private Timestamp initialMailSent;

    @Column(name = "LastReminderSent")
    private Timestamp lastReminderSent;

    @Column(name = "Active")
    private boolean active;
```

The method in controller:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = EXTERNAL_EFFORT_LINK_MANAGEMENT_URL + "/advancedSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public PagedResources<ExternalEffortLinkManagement> advancedSearch(
            @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search,
            Pageable pageable, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler
    ) {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority[] allowedRoles = {SYSADMIN, SUBCONTRACTOR_MANAGEMENT}; // <-- Debug point was here

        GeneralPredicateBuilder<ExternalEffortLinkManagement> builder = new GeneralPredicateBuilder<ExternalEffortLinkManagement>(ExternalEffortLinkManagement.class);
        Predicate predicate = predicateService.getPredicateFromParameters(parameters, ExternalEffortLinkManagement.class);
        Page<ExternalEffortLinkManagement> results = service.advancedSearch(
                this.buildAdvancedSearch(search, predicate, builder), pageable, allowedRoles);
        return super.toPagedResource(results, persistentEntityResourceAssembler);
    }
```

The Repository:

```java
@CrossOrigin(exposedHeaders="Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = EXTERNAL_EFFORT_LINK_MANAGEMENT_URL, path = EXTERNAL_EFFORT_LINK_MANAGEMENT_URL)
public interface ExternalEffortLinkManagementRepositoryExtEff extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ExternalEffortLinkManagement, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ExternalEffortLinkManagement>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<ExternalEffortLinkManagement> {

};
```

The service method:

```java
    public Page<ExternalEffortLinkManagement> advancedSearch(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, SimpleGrantedAuthority[] roles){
        if (SecurityUtils.userHasAnyRole(roles)) {
            return this.calcSumHours(this.repository.findAll(predicate, pageable));
        } else throw new ForbiddenException(FORBIDDEN);
    }
```

Now your have seen the code, let me explain the behaviour clearly.

1. At first I run `gradle clean`, than `gradle build` and than the application. After that, I do a request (doesn't matter if I do it from the app or directly in the browser or Postman etc., result is the same) `advancedSearch?page=0&size=10&sort=employee,asc&sort=active,asc&month=1&year=2020`. Everything is fine the results are sorted by the `employee` first and than by `active`.
2. Now I stop the application, `gradle build`, run the application. Doing the request again, the `employee` is ignored in the sorting, the results are only sorted by the `active` flag.
3. Now, again, I stop the application, `gradle build`, run the application. Doing the request again, everything is working. I didn't run `clean`! And I didn't changed anything in the source code.
4. Now, again fourth time, I stop the application, `gradle build`, run the application. Doing the request again, the `employee` is ignored in the sorting, the results are only sorted by the `active` flag. After the fourth build, I is not working any more until I run the `clean` command.

To make it more complicated than it already is, the behaviour is similar for some of the entity attributes. It doesn't matter if I combine the sorting parameters or just use one.

- `employee`: working sometimes
- `projectNumber`: working sometimes
- `initialMailSent`, `lastReminderSent`, `active`: working always (also in combination with each other)

When employee is not `working`, `projectNumber` is also not working, on the other side if one is working, the other is working as well.

The filters (`month`, `year`) are always the same and they doesn't seam to have influence on the behaviour.

Querdsl is generating some classes, so I thought these classes might cause the problem. But it doesn't seams so, because I have nearly the same problem within the continues integration chain, there it is toggling between working in the first build, not working in the second, working in the third and so on. So just steps 2 and 3. In the chain the build starts always with a clean code (no generated classes, they were generated during the build).

Does anyone have the same problem and better a explanation and solution?

Comment: This seems to be more build related problem then the code problem. Try to delete your m2 repository and see if it helps

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what's a m2 repository

Comment: Okay, I found it out. But this does not explain the behaviour for the continues integration. We use Azure and the Clients needs always to install everything from the stats, this means, gradla as it self and all dependencies

Comment: I cleaned my gradle cache, no change

Comment: Well, It was a good guess, but still based on the fact that the same code works for some build and doesn't work for another build (provided that within the same build the behavior is consistent) I would still hold to the opinion that it is a build-related problem and not a bug in the code

Comment: I think your right, but I have no clue where the problem might be. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of search I finally found the problem.

We had some "old" entity class `ExternalEffortLinkManagement` with nearly the same attributes, but `employee` and `projectNumber` where missing. This class was placed in an other package. This explains why all the other attributes have always been accepted as valid sort parameters, but not employee and projectNumber.

It seams like the java `build` is mixing up these two classes (old and new one). I currently don't understand why the builds where using sometimes the new class sometimes the old class.

**But removing the old class fixed the problem.** I still think the inconsistency between the builds must be a bug in the compiler or something similar, because for me it doesn't make sense, that sometimes `class a from package a` is used and sometimes `class a form package b`.